# Jquery function in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question regarding this code:

```
jQuery( "#unknown_dialog" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: true, 
    height:150,
    width:500,
    modal: true,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    open: function(event, ui) {
            jQuery(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
            jQuery(".ui-dialog-buttonpane").addClass("dialogButtonPane");
        jQuery(".ui-dialog-buttonset").addClass("dialogButtonSet");
        jQuery(".ui-button").addClass("dialogButton");
    }
```

});

I have tried to put open function as a different method for using it in multiple places like:

```
jQuery( "#unknown_dialog" ).dialog({
    ....,
    open: dialogOpenMethod(event, ui)
});

var dialogOpenMethod = function(event, ui) {
        jQuery(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
        jQuery(".ui-dialog-buttonpane").addClass("dialogButtonPane");
    jQuery(".ui-dialog-buttonset").addClass("dialogButtonSet");
    jQuery(".ui-button").addClass("dialogButton");
};
```

But I am getting javascript error in dialogOpenMethod(event, ui): *argument ui is not found*.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
jQuery( "#unknown_dialog" ).dialog({
    ....,
    open: dialogOpenMethod(event, ui)
    // calls the function ^^^^^^^^^^^
});
```

...is **calling** the `dialogOpenMethod` function and then assigning its return value to the `open` property, exactly the way `a = foo()` **calls** `foo` and assigns its return value to `a`.

Instead, just refer to the function:

```
jQuery( "#unknown_dialog" ).dialog({
    ....,
    open: dialogOpenMethod
});
```

Comment: It would be great if you can share any link where I can get more info on regard. Thanks.

Comment: @Ramson: This is fundamental JavaScript. Functions are objects, and so you can refer to them just like any other object; when you put `(..)` after them, you *call* them. Any JavaScript tutorial or book should talk about passing function references around.